# Flux integrals and parametrization of a curve

Tags: integration

Consider the velocity field $\mathbf{v}=-y\mathbf{i}+x\mathbf{j}$. 
Evaluate the line integral
$\int_{C} \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n} \ ds$, directly to calculate the net outward flux from a circle of radius $1$ centred at $x=1$, $y=0$. Report the flux through the lower and upper halves of the circle as well.

How would I parametrize this curve?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPpLJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $\mathbf{v}=-y\mathbf{i}+x\mathbf{j}$ and $C=\{(x,y):(x-1)^2+y^2=1\}$. Then $C$ can be parametrized as $x(t)=1+\cos t$ and $y(t)=\sin t$ with $t\in[0,2\pi)$ and the outward normal is $\mathbf{n}=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$.

Hence the outword flux thru the circle $C$ is given by
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n} \ dt,$$

The  the outword flux thru the upper half of $C$ is 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n} \ dt,$$
and the flux thru the lower half of $C$ is
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n} \ dt.$$

Can you take it from here?